# Why is Vagrant creating very different output in one of the provision lines?

Tags: vagrant

Why is my vagrant transforming this provision line:

```
echo "eval \"\$(starship init bash)\"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

in this line in .bashrc ?

```
eval  __main() { local major="${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}" local minor="${BASH_VERSINFO[1]}" if ((major > 4)) || { ((major == 4)) && ((minor >= 1)); }; then source <(/usr/local/bin/starship init bash --print-full-init) else source /dev/stdin <<<"$(/usr/local/bin/starship init bash --print-full-init)" fi } __main unset -f __main
```

This is the result of executing `$(starship init bash)` but it shouldn't be executing, once I'm only doing an echo.

How can I avoid it ?

**Edit**

With single quotes the result is the same, yet formatted.

I tried to run the command `echo "eval \"\$(starship init bash)\"" >> ~/.bashrc` inside the VM and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Try using single-quotes (`'`) instead of double-quotes (`"`).

Comment: See the edit I made

Comment: Strange, what is the result with single quotes?

Comment: Why not just use `echo "eval $(starship init bash)" >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: @harrymc as I said in the edit, the result with single quotes is the same, yet formatted. Instead of a single line, the result apears indented in serveral lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 problems:

First, as @harrymc said, I should have used single quotes. But instead of using single quotes in the outside of the string I used them like this:

```
echo "eval \'\$(starship init bash)\'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

That continued to created an expanded string instead of what I was intending.

The 2nd problem is that I forgot the -e switch in echo which disabled the interpretation of backslash escapes.

So the correct line is this:

```
echo -e 'eval \"\$(starship init bash)\"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Thanks to all that helped.